# Downscaling a fabric js element

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I need my user to be able to use fabric js to draw a number in a canvas element, and then for that drawing to be downscaled and ran through a neural network.

I've tried browsing through forums and documentation but couldn't anything directly related to my situation. I've tried using FileReader but I don't know if it has the tools necessary for this. The code below is just for reading and downloading the canvas element for testing purposes.

```
imageSaver.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", 
                                 "image/octet-stream"); 
    window.location.href=image; 
}, false);
```

Comment: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toDataURL, you can use multiplier, quality